# Erro: "classifier 'nome da classe' does not have a companion object,"

Tags: kotlin

Meu código

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {

    val listaDeLikes = listOf(
        RelacaoDeLike(323423,1), //Usuario 323423 deu like no post 1
        RelacaoDeLike(234234,1), //Usuario 234234 deu like no post 1
        RelacaoDeLike(456456,1), //Usuario 456456 deu like no post 1
        RelacaoDeLike(233424,2), //Usuario 233424 deu like no post 2
        RelacaoDeLike(466656,2), //Usuario 466656 deu like no post 2
        RelacaoDeLike(536853,2), //Usuario 536853 deu like no post 2
        RelacaoDeLike(456456,2), //Usuario 456456 deu like no post 2
        RelacaoDeLike(464645,3), //Usuario 464645 deu like no post 3
        RelacaoDeLike(787423,3), //Usuario 787423 deu like no post 3
        RelacaoDeLike(685344,3), //Usuario 685344 deu like no post 3
        RelacaoDeLike(987987,3)  //Usuario 987987 deu like no post 3
    )

    val postId = 2     
    val totalDeLikes = contarNumeroDeLikes(postId, RelacaoDeLike)        
    println(">>> Aqui está o resultado: o post $postId tem um total de $totalDeLikes likes.")
}

fun contarNumeroDeLikes(postId: Int, listaDeLikes: List<RelacaoDeLike>): Int {    
    var totalDeLikes = 0       
    return totalDeLikes    
}


class RelacaoDeLike(userId: Int, postId: Int): Object() {
    val userId = userId
    val postId = postId

    init {           
        println("Foi criado uma nova relação de like entre o usuário $userId e o post $postId")
    }    
}
```

Mensagem de erro:

> source.kt:22:52: error: classifier 'RelacaoDeLike' does not have a companion object, and thus must be initialized here
>       val totalDeLikes = contarNumeroDeLikes(postId, RelacaoDeLike)
>                                                      ^

Answer (score 6, accepted):

É um erro de digitação.

Esta linha

```
val totalDeLikes = contarNumeroDeLikes(postId, RelacaoDeLike)
```

Deveria ser

```
val totalDeLikes = contarNumeroDeLikes(postId, listaDeLikes)
```

[Veja funcionando em try.kotlinlang](https://try.kotlinlang.org/#/UserProjects/9oa73qq1gc57m6mvcrfpfs6f11/d5a10l9nt51pk65bm82jain5cq).